# $body variable not working

Tags: theming

I am in a custom tpl.php file [node--netrunner-card--Operation--full.tpl.php].
This is for a custom content type [netrunner_card].

I am trying to output the contents of the $body variable and unable to do so via the prescribed avenue. I copied node.tpl.php into my theme and renamed it. I can output the contents of body but I have to do this like so:

```
print render($body[0]['value']);
```

I should be able to do it like so:

```
print render($body);
```

But the second option renders nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the documentation for [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) says, in the description for the `$content` variable.

> An array of node items. Use [render($content)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) to print them all, or print a subset such as [render($content['field_example'])](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7). Use [hide($content['field_example'])](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7) to temporarily suppress the printing of a given element.

The node body is a field, and you should use `render($content['body'])` to render it.

The note about field variables is the following one:

> Field variables: for each field instance attached to the node a corresponding variable is defined; for example, $node->body becomes $body. When needing to **access a field's raw values, developers/themers are strongly encouraged to use these variables**. Otherwise they will have to explicitly specify the desired field language; for example, $node->body['en'], thus overriding any language negotiation rule that was previously applied.

You should use `$body` only when you need to access the field's raw values, not to render the field.

Comment: I've read that section a hundred times now. I think I need to go get a drink and come back. My mind is whirling with trying to both learn AND implement this stuff while doing other things as well. Maybe I've got too much multi-tasking.

I will say that I feel like every post here brings me even closer to fully grasping Drupal on the level that I want to. I appreciate all the help from the drupal.stackexchange group.

Comment: Sometimes, it is easy to miss a single line and not understanding what the documentation says. It happened to me in the past, and I know what scratching your head for hours means. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ignore the notes in the node.tpl.php file and output like I did for all of my other fields, treating body like any other field instead of one of the two fields auto-created for all content types.

```
print render( $content['body'] );
```

This gives me the output I need!